# Comma Separated values in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `contacts` and i want to select all the distinct contact names (int) in one line separated by comma.

Currently i am using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM contacts
```

To get this result:

```
11111
22222
33333
```

But i need to have this result:

```
11111, 22222, 33333
```

I saw some examples with XML PATH but i couldn't adapt it to my code. Can anybody help me with the query please?

Comment: this might be what you are looking for? http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/04/sql-server-create-a-comma-delimited-list-using-select-clause-from-table-column/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`STUFF` + `XML PATH` will do the job:

```
SELECT STUFF(
             (SELECT Distinct ',' + cast (name as varchar(20)) 
              FROM contacts       
              FOR XML PATH (''))
             , 1, 1, '')
```

demo:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/748e4/1

Comment: so your name column is `int` - added cast as varchar..

Answer (score 0):

You can use STUFF:

```
SELECT 
    STUFF((
      SELECT distinct ',' + c.contacts
      FROM dbo.contacts c
      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as names;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       declare @t table  (Name Varchar(50))

       Insert into @t (Name) values ('1111'), ('2222'), ('3333')

        DECLARE @tt VARCHAR(MAX) 
        SELECT @tt= COALESCE(@tt + ', ', '') + Name from @t 
        SELECT @tt AS Result

OR 

   declare @t table  (Name Varchar(50))

   Insert into @t (Name) values ('1111'), ('2222'), ('3333')

SELECT SUBSTRING(
(SELECT ',' + s.Name
FROM @t s
ORDER BY s.Name
FOR XML PATH('')),2,200000) As Names
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @contacts table(name nvarchar(100))

INSERT INTO @contacts (name) VALUES
('John'),
('Andrew'),
('Paul')

DECLARE @Result AS NVARCHAR(1000) -- Or even MAX if you need

SELECT @Result = ISNULL(@Result + ', ', '') + C.name
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM @contacts) C

SELECT @Result -- This is your actual result
```

The only thing you need to watch for is that the DISTINCT may affect the order of the names. That may or may not matter to you.